# Values are not passed from the method in component to the html template in Angular5. (*ngIf is not working)

Tags: angular

I am trying to call the function of the child component from the parent component.

**Parent.component.html**

```
<div class="collapse list-unstyled">
<div *ngFor="let data of data1; let i=index">
<li>
<a  class="dropdown-item menu-item" (click)= callchild(i)  >
                                {{data.item}} 
</a>
</li>
</div>
```

**Parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(  private child: ChildComponent) { }

callchild(i){
this.child.menu(i);

}
```

From parent.component.html I am making the call to function callchild(i) which is the function present in parent.component.ts. From this component I am making call to the function menu(i) which is part of Child component.

**Child.component.ts**

```
menu(i){
this.visible = true;
}
```

In this menu(i) function, I am setting the value of visible to be true.

**Child.component.html**

```
   <div class="row"  *ngIf="visible; then item1"> 
   </div> 
   <ng-template #item1 >

   </ng-template>
```

After setting the value of visible to be true I expected the content inside ng-template to be seen. But it is not loading. 
If I make the call to menu(i) from Child.component.html then it successfully loads the content inside ng-template. But I want to make the call to menu(i) from Parent component and then load the contents of child component. 
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like @ViewChildren ?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: '<div > content here <div *ngIf="isVisible"> will show on click</div> </div>',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    isVisible=false
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: '<app-child *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="setVisible(item)"></app-child>',
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) itemsList: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
    items;
    setVisible(item){
      this.itemsList.forEach((it) => {
        if(it.id === item.id){ // <== or whatever strategy you need here
            it.isVisible = true;
        }
      })
   }
}
```

Hope this will help!